# How to iterate through all members of a guild and changing their nicknames with a Discord bot built on JDA

Tags: java, discord

I am trying to write a simple call that lists all users of a guild, checks if they have clan tags next to their name and if not adds them, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I'm getting NullPointers when checking the nicknames so I presume I am not getting those values correctly.

I am good with Java I've just never used JDA before. I can't find any code examples of something as simple as listing all members and iterating through them. Could someone please point me in the right direction? I have done a bit on REST in university but not a lot.

Adding catch blocks but I'm not getting the values of any of the nicknames into my list so my code isn't doing anything. I've tried implementing in Lists, arrays and arraylists but it seems the issue is getting the information from the guild itself.

```
if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!tags")){
        Guild guild = event.getGuild();
        List<Member> users = guild.getMembers();
        for(Member member: users){
            String s = "";
            try{
                s = member.getNickname();
                if(!member.getNickname().startsWith("[NNN]")) {
                    try {
                        member.modifyNickname("[NNN]" + member.getNickname()).queue();
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ignored){ }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to narrow down a bit more where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nickname is nullable because a user can choose not to set one, this is represented by returning null. You can check this by doing `s == null || !s.startsWith("[NNN]")`. Alternatively you can use `getEffectiveName` which will return the username if the nickname was not set for the server:

```java
Member self = guild.getSelfMember();
for (Member member : guild.getMembers()) {
    String name = member.getEffectiveName(); // username or nickname
    if (!name.startsWith("[NNN]") && self.canInteract(member)) {
        member.modifyNickname("[NNN]" + name).queue();
    }
}
```

I used `canInteract` to avoid hierarchy exceptions which will inevitably occur if you try to set the nickname of either the owner of the server or a member who has a higher role than your bot.

Comment: this is great. Couple things I need to think about when rewriting it. Thanks a lot for the explanation and for pointing out the canInteract method. I had tried looking for a getName method that would do something similar but this is perfect. Thank you very much for your help +1